# How to un-tar a file in s3 without passing through local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a huge tar file in an s3 bucket that I want to decompress while remaining in the bucket. I do not have enough space on my local machine to download the tar file and upload it back to the s3 bucket. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Tar files aren't compressed: they're just concatenated files . Or do you have a `.tar.gz` file?

Comment: Assuming it's a non-compressed `.tar` then you _could_ use Ranged HTTP requests to retrieve only each `.tar` header. I'm not an S3 user, but I assume S3 has some way of creating a new blob/object from a byte-range of another blob/object...

Comment: Nice idea, but while a `Range` can be specified with a `GetObject`, it doesn't seem to be available for `CopyObject`.

Comment: Its not possible to do it directly in S3.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 does not have in-built functionality to manipulate files (such as compressing/decompressing).

I would recommend:

- **Launch an Amazon EC2 instance** in the same region as the bucket
- **Login** to the EC2 instance
- **Download** the file from S3 using the AWS CLI
- **Untar** the file
- **Upload** desired files back to S3 using the AWS CLI

Amazon EC2 instances are charged per-second, so choose a small machine (eg `t3a.micro`) and it will be rather low-cost (perhaps under 1 cent).